# how mobile application call Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a demo mobile application which work with Web API. I follow this sites:

- [Creating a Web API that Supports CRUD Operations](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations)
- [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

This is how I call the Web API:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");

            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
    }
```

and this is how an API function is called:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/products").Result;  // Blocking call!
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Parse the response body. Blocking!
    var products = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>().Result;
    foreach (var p in products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1};\t{2}", p.Name, p.Price, p.Category);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
}
```

I don't understand this line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/products").Result;
```

What is called when using the `api/products` address? A model, controller class of API or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the first page you referenced:

> To get the list of all products, add this method to the ProductsController class:
>
> ```
> public class ProductsController : ApiController
> {
>     public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
>     {
>         return repository.GetAll();
>     }
>     // ....
> }
> ```
>
> The method name starts with "Get", so by convention it maps to GET requests. Also, because the method has no parameters, it maps to a URI that does not contain an "id" segment in the path.

So, the call to

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/products").Result;
```

will call the `products` controller's function that starts with `Get` and that has no parameter.

If you are not familiar with controllers, you can learn more about the MVC pattern on the [ASP.NET MVC Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview).

Answer (score 0):

`HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/products").Result` means send a request to the Product controller which is an API controller. Once product controller processes your request, store its result in an instance of HttpResponseMessage.

If you put a breakpoint, you will see that response contains a list of products (I assume that this is what the Product controller does).